# Playwright does not generate report in Docker

Tags: docker, playwright

I have the following playwright configuration that works as intended when run from command line. (Reports are generated.)

**playwright.config.ts**

```js
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './tests',
  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: [
    ['html']
  ],
  use: {
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },
```

**Terminal**

`CI=true npx playwright test 000-authentication.spec.ts || ls`

**Logs**

```
(...)
  1 failed
    tests/000-authentication.spec.ts:14:7 › Authentication User Flow › User can log in 
  1 skipped
Dockerfile              README.md               package-lock.json       playwright-report       src                     tests
compose.yml             node_modules            package.json            playwright.config.ts    test-results            tsconfig.json
```

However, when I run it from docker the reports are not generated. I checked that with `ls` and with `playwright show-reports` as well.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.40.0-jammy

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/
COPY src /app/src/           # Location of page objects
COPY tests /app/tests/       # Location of tests
COPY tsconfig.json /app/

RUN npm install

ARG CI=true

CMD ["npm", "run", "test:ci"]
```

**Terminal**

`docker run -it --rm --ipc=host e2e-tests sh -c "npx playwright test 000-authentication.spec.ts || npx playwright show-report || ls"`

**Logs**

```
(...)
  1 failed
    tests/000-authentication.spec.ts:14:7 › Authentication User Flow › User can log in 
  1 skipped
No report found at "/app/playwright-report"
node_modules  package-lock.json  package.json  src  test-results  tests  tsconfig.json
```

Initially I run docker container without any additional flags and parameters.
I tried with suggested parameters from [Playwright documentation](https://playwright.dev/docs/docker) with no change in results.
I tried to change reporter without results.

How can I generate reports in Docker container?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to generate reporsts with the `--reporter` argument.

Then I noticed that my `playwright-config.ts` file was not copied onto the image.

After fixing this issue everything works as expected.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.40.0-jammy

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json /app/
COPY src /app/src/              # Location of page objects
COPY tests /app/tests/          # Location of tests
COPY tsconfig.json /app/
COPY playwright.config.ts /app/ # Config is needed if we want to use custom setup, obviously

RUN npm install

ARG CI=true

CMD ["npm", "run", "test:ci"]
```