Having trouble running Playwright .NET test inside of a Docker Container
I am currently working on a proof-of-concept for a proposal my company is doing. The idea we have put together for executing automated tests is to build out probably a Specflow framework for UI and API testing, which would be containerized and deployed to run in Azure Kubernetes Service, since AKS is way cheaper than dedicated azure virtual machines. We have been having trouble getting our UI tests to run in the Docker container. Me and my team don't have much experience with Docker so the work is going slow.
I put together a few basic tests with Specflow and Playwright, just to go to a webpage and verify the title (since this is just a demo). I was able to get a docker image to build and the container was running but I'm having trouble verifying if the test ran or not. I was expecting some sort of test result output from the 'dotnet test' command like I would see in powershell but couldn't see anything like that in the docker container.
This is the Dockerfile for the image that successfully built and ran as a container:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/dotnet:v1.42.0-jammy as playwright

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AutomatedTestFrameworkProject/UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj", "AutomatedTestFrameworkProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./AutomatedTestFrameworkProject/UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AutomatedTestFrameworkProject"
RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit --version 1.27.1
RUN dotnet build "./UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
RUN dotnet test "./UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.dll"]
Run dotnet test "./UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION

The next Dockerfile after I made some edits failed to build the image, and it failed at the 'dotnet test' command with the error 'process "/bin/sh -c dotnet test "./UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION" did not complete successfully: unable to find user app: no matching entries in passwd file'
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/dotnet:v1.42.0-jammy as playwright

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
USER app
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AutomatedTestFrameworkProject/UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj", "AutomatedTestFrameworkProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./AutomatedTestFrameworkProject/UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AutomatedTestFrameworkProject"
RUN dotnet add package Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit --version 1.27.1
RUN dotnet build "./UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.dll"]
Run dotnet test "./UserInterfacePlaywrightFramework.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated!

Will test report options help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67739060/playwright-test-execution-report https://www.lambdatest.com/learning-hub/playwright-reporting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77547195/playwright-does-not-generate-report-in-docker

Couple of things that triggered me technically:

Playwright is recommended to be used with .NET 8.0 :)
Specflow is deprecated. You should migrate/refactor Reqnroll
Do you also have a docker-compose.yml file? It makes building and running your container more easy and future proof (if it gets any bigger).

With what command are you starting up your image? If you want to interact with the container when running it you should run the image with: docker run -it 
Moreover in your first code block (the succesfully ran container) change the last code section to this:

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test", "--logger:trx"]

Then build your image "docker build -t [yourTagName] ."
And run the container with "docker run -it [yourTagName]"
